# Hotstrings on a bash console

Tags: linux, bash, alias, console

I can do things like this to alias often used things `alias iii='sudo yum install'` and that works fine, but it's nice to be able to expand a command on the command line as I use it. For sure I can type `alias` to show all of the aliases, and I can even do `command -V <command>` to expand aliases or functions, but it sometimes feels better to see the full layout of a command than aliases.

I think this is possible in bash, but I don't know how. With the above example, Could someone describe how to type `i`, then `i`, then `i`, then `space`, and for that to instantly delete the 3x i's to replace everything by `sudo yum install`  after which I can continue to type what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `bash` it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> known as shell-expand-line (type `bind -p |grep shell-expand-line` to see it bind to which keys); check it by

type your `iii` alias created then press above keys combination short-cut.

Note that this shortcut expands almost everything, like variable expansion, command-substitution, process-substitution and others as well not only aliases, so ***be careful when using it***

Comment: That's great. I like that, so I don't need to do anything fancy, just keep my aliases as is and expand them. Thanks.